# BalancedPayments : Credit card Authorization failure or Card has become invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, balanced-payments

I am writing a web application where the buyer can pay with a card she has previously used to purchase.

I need to know at a level of granularity:

1. when the card has authorization failure (usually due to insufficient funds or line of credit)  or
2. when the card has become invalid (for example, the card is already closed) .

Is there a response.status in BalancedPayments response indicating such response?  I seem to dig in the API reference and could not find anything.

BalancedPayments : Credit card authorization failure or card has become invalid?

https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api.html?language=bash#create-a-new-debit

Answer (score 2):

1) You will receive notice of an authorization failure as soon as you attempt to debit the card and will be returned one of the following error codes: https://github.com/balanced/balanced-api/blob/master/errors.rst

2) Unfortunately, there is no way to determine if a card has suddenly become invalid. You will only know if a card has been closed or is now invalid by attempting to debit it and receiving a failure notification.